# Access span via parent div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How I can access a specific `<span>` via its parent `<div>` like below:

```
<div>
<!--parent div-->
 <div>
   <span>...</span>
   <span>...</span>
 </div>
 <div>
   <span>...</span>
   <span>.. through parent div i can access this span ..</span>
 </div>
<!--close parent div-->
</div>
```

Edited:
There is a variable suppose **item.**.In this **item variable there are two values** shows i.e **(item = name size)**
I break this variable **through jquery in to parts..ie.item[0]=name; item[1]=size;**
Now I print the **name in parent div span...and size in child div span through jquery...**

```
<div>
    <!--parent div-->
     <span>...Print Name...</span>
     <div>
       <span>...</span>
       <span>...</span>
     </div>
     <div>
       <span>...</span>
       <span>.. Print Size.. ..</span>
     </div>
    <!--close parent div-->
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean 'through parent div'? Something like `$('div span')`?

Comment: what are you asking to do? do you want to access the span from parent div or other way around?

Comment: Describe how exactly you want it selected? Second span in second div?

Comment: Or are you specifically asking how to access a particular sibling child element? If so, you want to look here: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: Yes, we need more clarification. What are we selecting. A Span with particular content? A span with a specific index? A span with a specific parent?

Comment: If you want to access each span separately you need to provide an id for that div. If you want to access it as a group you need to provide a class. Also you can access it by element type. And rest code is available.
http://api.jquery.com/children/
http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: I Edited my question.please check it

Comment: We need you to explain your HTML structure. It is always going to be this structure? Can you give your HTML elements IDs or Classes? That'd be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to select that particular span from the parent div you need something like this:

```
parentDiv = $(element); // assuming you know which parent you're talking about
$('> div:eq(1) > span:eq(1)', parentDiv);
```

But it would be far easier to give your `<span>` a class name, e.g.

```
<span class="my-span">hello</span>
```

In that case, selecting it will be something like:

```
parentDiv.find('.my-span');
```

[**Example**](http://jsbin.com/azoyuh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I Think this is where your looking for

> $("div span").click(function () {
>
> ```
>     });
> ```

or if you need to get it with css

```
div span{

}
```

and select just one span

```
<div>
    <!--parent div-->
     <div>
       <span>...</span>
       <span>...</span>
     </div>
     <div>
       <span>...</span>
       <span id="someid">.. through parent div i can access this span ..</span>
     </div>
    <!--close parent div-->
    </div>
```

first add an ID

```
$("#someid").click(function () {

          });
```